# Double Form Submission on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im using codeigniter, and I have a double form submission problem. I looked for a solution on google about 2-3 days ago, but I still didn't manage to find one. Can someone help me?

**shopping_cart.php**

```
<?php

echo anchor("user/item_all", "Continue to shopping", array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-info'
));
if ($this->cart->total_items() > 0):
       if ($return_checkout) {
                echo anchor("user/checkout", "Checkout", array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right',
                    'style' => "margin-left: 10px",


                ));
        }

        echo anchor("user/destroy_cart", "Delete All Cart", array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'style' => "margin: 0px 10px"
        ));
        echo form_button(array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right',
            'style' => "margin: 0px 10px",
            'content' => "Update Cart"
        ));
endif;
?>
```

User.php

```
function checkout() {

    $return_checkout = $this->session->userdata('poin') >= $this->cart->total() ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $cart = $this->cart->contents();
    if ($return_checkout AND count($cart) > 0) {
        if ($this->mall->checkout($cart)) {

            $this->cart->destroy();
            redirect('user/shop_history');
        }
    }else
        redirect('user/shop_history');
    }
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any errors or such? Because I see some syntax errors in your user.php file.

Comment: No i didn't, i just get double form submission, im planning to disable purchase button after a single click to avoid double form submission. but i don't know how. i am new at php oop.

Comment: Could you then also show us the form?

Comment: Does it always double submit? Is it caused by doubleclick?

Comment: One way: Each cart has a unique id and a date that is recorded in the database with a status? When it is checked out the status is updated? when they try and check it out again they get an error? You can delete all carts from the database after a certain age. this is quite reliable. Any cart that is not in the database on checkout is an error. etc. Please do not just use the session - imo, that will end in confusion.

Comment: @Pat4561 here's my form btw http://zenon-development.com/form_helper.txt

Comment: @Goose yes, if you submit the purchase button and click it twice, the items will be duplicated when purchase but your points still cost on single item. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: anyway i thankyou all for all suggestion. my problem is fix now. i thought it was a button and i checked on inspect element it's a href tag. problem solve.